# What is the JDBC type for ctid in postgres?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I cannot seem to set the proper type in a prepared statement.  This code:

```
String sql = "delete from foo where ctid = ?";
PreparedStatement deleteStmt = conn.prepareStatement( sql );
deleteStmt.setString(1, "(0,43)");  // select ctid from foo shows (0,43) exists....
int a = deleteStmt.executeUpdate();
```

throws this exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: tid = character varying
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.   Position: 28
```

Note that from psql, the delete works using a string:

```
mydb=# DELETE FROM foo where ctid = '(0,43)';
DELETE 1
```

What is the proper type/encoding for a tid in a JDBC PreparedStatement?  I have tried setRowId() (throws ava.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4PreparedStatement.setRowId(int, RowId) is not yet implemented.)  and setBytes()   (throws ...operator does not exist: tid = byte)

Comment: What if you try with `deleteStmt.setObject(1, "(0,43)");`? What exception does it throw?

Comment: Another possible solution: `setString(1, "(0,43)::ctid")` or don't use a PreparedStatement and use a dynamic SQL.

Comment: Both setObject(1, "(0,43)") and setString(1, "(0,43)::ctid") throw org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: tid = character varying.  Dynamic SQL with no substitutions on a PreparedStatement (e.g.  sql = "delete from foo where ctid = '(0,50)'"; deleteStmt = conn.prepareStatement( sql ); )  DOES work.

Comment: else - if possible - change your datatype to varchar

Comment: ctid is an internal column of type tid and cannot be changed.

Comment: You write nice questions though ;-) ... to bad about all the effort you put into that other one. Please note: there is https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ... but be sure to study their help center carefully before you put up a question there. And in case you do: feel free to drop me a link. I never used that community, and I am wondering if it comes up with good answers for such requests!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!   You have to manually create a PGO object and set the type and value and pass it to JDBC as a object.   This now works:

```
sql = "delete from foo where ctid = ?";
deleteStmt = conn.prepareStatement( sql );
org.postgresql.util.PGobject pgo = new org.postgresql.util.PGobject();
pgo.setType("tid");
pgo.setValue("(0,54)");  // value is a string as might be returned in select ctid from foo and then resultSet.getString(1);
deleteStmt.setObject(1, pgo);

int a = deleteStmt.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("delete returns " + a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Old topic, but I would like to add that writing

```
where ctid = ?::tid";
```

instead of

```
where ctid = ?::ctid";
```

did the trick. It is then possible to use PreparedStatement.setString(x, "(10,3)")